# selecting an ids list to apply an update query in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to update some table rows. I've tried to make a query that updates my table row by selecting some row id's from a select query in this way:

```
UPDATE `subsequence` SET `tcStart`= `tcStart`+1  WHERE ID_subsequence 
in (select ID_subsequence from subsequence join sequence on subsequence.ID_sequence 
= sequence.ID_sequence WHERE sequence.tcStart = subsequence.tcStart)
```

When i try to execute it, I have this error message :

```
#1093 - You can't specify target table 'subsequence' for update in FROM clause
```

So any help please !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Error 1093 - Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)

Comment: Not exactly the same issue

Comment: Well, as it contains this in the answer: "In MySQL, you can't modify the same table which you use in the SELECT part.", it is pretty much exactly the same.